# FullCalendar background color issue

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar, background-color

I have this piece of code:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    if (allDay) {
        alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
    }else{
        alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
    }
    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

As you can see this changes the background color of a date cell when clicked... what i'm trying to do is changing the background color when a condition is fulfil, but this condition is not evaluated when clicking the date cell...

Anyone knows how to achive this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: which condition is this? is date?

Comment: you have to select elements according to your condition, so answer is difficult to guess

Comment: check this http://jsbin.com/atirav/2/edit this is selecting by date

Answer (score 0):

allDay will be set to true false if the user has clicked on a slot in the agendaWeek or agendaDay views. Otherwise, it will be true.

Refer this link http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/